# Can I put 2 quotes in one sentence in my essay?

Tags: structure, essay, quotes

In my essay I want to use 2 quotes that are both on the same page but are 4 lines apart. I didn't think I should use ellipsis b/c the passages I want to quote are quite far apart.

What I want to write is:
Oedipus tells them, “Your pain strikes each of you alone, each in the confines of himself, no other. But my spirit grieves for the city, for myself and all of you” (162), and then says, “I sent Creon . . . to learn what I might do or say to save our city” (162).

Is this the correct?

Comment: //Oedipus tells them, “Your pain strikes each of you alone, each in the confines of himself, no other. But my spirit grieves for the city, for myself and all of you” (162), and then says, “I sent Creon . . . to learn what I might do or say to save our city” (162).//  Instead of ...and then says,... you may consider "...and then he adds, "I sent Creon . . ."  About the first quote, is it ...himself.... or 'yourself'?  Otherwise, I don't think the way quotes are given seems OK.

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple quotations in sentences. Better students tend to do so. For example, in English Literature GCSE exams in the United Kingdom, better students use more than one short quotation per sentence than poorer students, who use one long quotation.